# How to unlock the "Science is done by Quantity" achievement?

Tags: achievements, helldivers-2

The "Science is done by Quantity" achievement has a description that says you need to extract a mission with at least 15 common samples.  I've done this with my friend multiple times now, but the achievement has not been awarded.

I've read online that you have to be playing solo for this achievement, and that you as an individual player need to be holding at all 15 (or more) samples (i.e. it cannot be spread across teammates).  But I've read some conflicting information on these statements.

Furthermore, there is an additional, similar achievement  called "Science is done by Quality" in which you must extract with at least 15 *rare* samples.  I've read online for this achievement that the samples *can* be spread across teammates.  While I guess it's possible the two achievements work differently, I would find it strange if they did seeing that the only difference in their descriptions is the type of sample to collect.

What are the requirements to unlock the "Science is done by Quantity" achievement?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have both of the achievements you mentioned.

[image]

The Steam Achievements page lists the following for "Science is done by Quantity":

> Extract with at least 15 common samples.

And the following for "Science is done by Quality" (which has recently been renamed "Samples are a diver's best friend"):

> Extract at least 15 rare samples from a mission as a team.

This description makes the "Quality" one a lot more clear (and is indeed how I got it). The "Quantity" one is very vague, like you mentioned, but I can confirm that **you must be the holder of at least 15 common samples when you extract to receive the achievement. They cannot be split across your teammates.**

You don't have to be playing solo so long as, in your possession, you have at least 15 **common** samples. They do need to be common; you can't have, say, 13 common and 2 rare samples.

You can't easily see how many of the samples your team has that're held by you, specifically, as the UI doesn't quite support this yet. You can see how many your team has by, by default, pressing Tab (keyboard) or the Touchpad (PS5) to pull up the map. The sample count is in the top-right.

If you want to play with a friend and guarantee the achievement, complete your mission as normal (being sure to collect at least 15 common samples between you both) and when the time comes to extract, have your friend drop their samples by holding the default X key (keyboard) or down on the D-pad (PS5) and choosing the "Drop samples" button. You can then pick them up, extract, and get the achievement.

Comment: Helldivers 2 *just* renamed the 15 rare samples achievement to "Samples are a diver's best friend" **as I was writing this answer**. Unbelievable timing.

Comment: Oh didn't realize the rare sample one _actually_ said that (my friend told me the achievement existed but not the full description, and I didn't check myself admittedly)

Comment: Quick note that while you cannot directly see how many samples you are carrying it is possible to drop the samples on keyboard by holding x and selecting the bottom right option (the cursor is controlled with the same buttons as when you hold r for weapon options). When dropping the samples it will display how many of each kind on the screen, also useful if you want to deposit samples at the extraction to save lugging them around or give them to another player before you introduce Democracy to a large terminid nest by yourself)