How do I check how many samples I'm carrying?
During a mission, how do I check how many samples I'm carrying? I know I can check how many samples my team is carrying by opening the map (Tab on Keyboard, Touchpad on PS5). However, I want to check my own samples because I'll be able to take more risks if I'm not carrying a lot.

Been a bit since I played but https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/407587/how-to-unlock-the-science-is-done-by-quantity-achievement#comment571617_407589 kind of is an answer or a workaround at least

That's suspiciously undemocratic of you...

@Neon1024 Samples are shared by all players. I want to know because I know I can take more risks if I'm not carrying a lot of samples.

I had assumed you wanted to know if you had 15 basic samples for the Science by Quantity achievement. If you want to take a risk, drop the samples!

@Neon1024 I honestly didn't know there was an achievement for carrying samples.
